# The role of Selenium in the Webdriver specs, and getting a browser to accept webdriver requests

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I am using Selenium right now to control Chrome.  I am confused by the Selenium protocol and the W3c standards regarding WebDrivers.

**QUESTION**: What's the relationship between Selenium's protocol and the Webdriver standard? And are the webdrivers built into the browsers themselves?

I know that browsers expose [webdriver interface](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#h-list-of-endpoints). That's basically a bunch of URLs.

More specifically (although they are different facets of the **same** question):

- I semi-understand that Selenium has a its own protocol, which is "similar" to what the W3 specs say. I couldn't find info about the differences. What are they? Are they converging?
- Why does Selenium need the Chromedriver? (and especially the Chromedriver browser) Can't it just connect straight to the Chrome instance?
- Selenium offers a server which then forwards the requests to a remote browser. My understanding is that the headless client talks to a server, which runs a headless Chrome and reports back to the headless client the answers. Is that just a pure "proxy"? Does the selenium server use the W3 API?
- If I wrote a thin layer around the W3 specs (that is, just a script that makesNow... 
  calls following the W3 protocol), how can I talk to the browser directly? I couldn't find any clear instructions anywhere on how to do that
- Again with my thin layer: if I wanted to control a remote browser, would I just need to proxy those calls to a server running a headless chrome?

I guess the question boils down to:

- If I wanted to get rid of Selenium altogether, and just use the specs naked, could I do just that? If so, how? And would would I "miss out" on?

**UPDATE 1**: I just realised that the ChromeDriver executable is actually released by Google itself. It's not Selenium! So, I guess I can just run the ChromeDriver command and connect to it...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I answered my own question. It was legit as it was, and didn't need any need to be narrowed down. Kindly remove the downvote, if you are one of the mensa members who did it. Thanks.

Comment: You should review [ask], especially how to ask a good question. A question is supposed to be a single question. If you look at what you have posted, you will see that you asked a LOT of questions. This is not a good format for SO.

Comment: So I guess you also downvoted my perfectly good answer because... it answered too many questions? I am not in the mood for this. To the community a favour, and take the downvote off. Really. I was too busy asking legit questions and providing good answers to follow the guidelines to the letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **I semi-understand that Selenium has a its own protocol, which is "similar" to what the W3 specs say. I couldn't find info about the differences. What are they? Are they converging?**

It wasn't ju has thest a different protocol... it was a different everything. [this document explains it all](http://www.erranderr.com/blog/webdriver-ontology.html). It boils down to Selenium releasing the 'Selenium JSON Wire Protocol' (they developed it between 2004 and 2009... a lifetime ago!) The long story short:

> A while after Selenium 2 was released, browser vendors started implementing the Selenium JSON Wire Protocol themselves! Yay! This makes a lot of sense: they’re in the best position to maintain the server side and they can build the necessary behaviour directly into the browser.
>   It started with OperaDriver in 2009-2011, and then others followed such as ChromeDriver and Mozilla’s geckodriver with Marionette.4 This is where the motivation for a WebDriver standard comes from.

The link has the rest of the story too.

> **Why does Selenium need the Chromedriver? (and especially the Chromedriver browser) Can't it just connect straight to the Chrome instance?**

The ChromeDriver is the piece of software that will accept HTTP calls in order to open a browser window and simulate user interaction. To keep things practical, Chromedriver will implement for example:

```
POST    /session    New Session
DELETE  /session/{session id}   Delete Session
GET /status Status
GET /ses has the has thesion/{session id}/timeouts  Get Timeouts
POST    /session/{session id}/timeouts  Set Timeouts
POST    /session/{session id}/url   Navigate To
GET /session/{session id}/url   Get Current URL
```

The calls are quite straightforward, and there aren't that many.

> **Selenium offers a server which then forwards the requests to a remote browser. My understanding is that the headless client talks to a server, which runs a headless Chrome and reports back to the headless client the answers. Is that just a pure "proxy"? Does the selenium server use the W3 API?**

Yes, you (well, me, that is) are right: it acts just as a proxy. But it can be pretty cool too! For example, you can connect to a remote WebDriver, and say "I want to use this browser, on this system"; the webdriver will have a list of specific drivers, and will try and run that command on a browser that complies with your requirements.

> **If I wrote a thin layer around the W3 specs (that is, just a script that makes calls following the W3 protocol), how can I talk to the browser directly? I couldn't find any clear instructions anywhere on how to do that**

You can't talk to the browser directly -- you talk to the ChromeDriver which in turn will do the talking for you :D

> **Again with my thin layer: if I wanted to control a remote browser, would I just need to proxy those calls to a server running a headless chrome?**

The Webdriver client doesn't need to know if it's talking to a proxy with 45 headless browsers and 3 different OSes under its belt. The protocol is the same regardless.

> **If I wanted to get rid of Selenium altogether, and just use the specs naked, could I do just that? If so, how? And what would I "miss out" on?**

You are most welcome to implement a library and skip the **selenium webdriver** library. [The specs are available](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html) and ready to be used. BUT! Keep in mind that only Firefox has a full implementation of the specs, Today, [Chrome's webdriver status is pretty poor](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkcr/docs/chromedriver_status.md), although that will change soon enough.